# Error in using Expression Language in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-2.5

> Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.spring.first.Item] for property 'item'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.spring.first.Item] for property 'item': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

server.java

```
package com.spring.first;
public class Server {
    private Item item;
    private String itemName;
    public Item getItem()
    {
        return item; 
    }

    public String getItemName()
    {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItem(Item item)
    {
        this.item=item;
    }
    public void setItemName(String str)
    {
        this.itemName=str;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Server [item ="+item+", itemName ="+itemName+"]";
    }
}
```

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int qty;
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getQty()
    {
        return qty;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public void setQty(int x)
    {
        this.qty=x;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Item [ name ="+name+", Qty ="+qty+"];";
    }

}
```

My configuration file

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="itemBean" class="com.spring.first.Item">
        <property name="name" value="itemA" />
        <property name="qty" value="10" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="serverBean" class="com.spring.first.Server">
        <property name="item" value="#{itemBean}" />
        <property name="itemName" value="#{itemBean.name}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I'm using Spring 2.5.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Exression Language (SPEL) was introduced in Spring 3 (refer to the [new features introduced in Spring 3](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-feature-el)), so it is not possible to use SPEL with Spring 2.5.6.

You will need to upgrade your Spring version to at least 3 (the best would be the latest version, which is currently 4.2.2). The configuration as you have it is correct and would work ([see SPEL reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based)).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing configuration file as follows

```
<bean id="itemBean" class="com.spring.first.Item">
    <property name="name" value="itemA" />
    <property name="qty" value="10" />
</bean>
<bean id="serverBean" class="com.spring.first.Server">
    <property name="item" ref="itemBean" />
    <property name="itemName" value="itemBean.name" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Sorry its wrong @fofo It will give the value to itemName to itemBean.name not item A :) BDW Thanks